# Creating Implementation of DatabaseConfigProvider

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, h2

I'm trying to test a Slick Play app without having to startup and run everything through a Play Application context (using H2). This is because I want to share H2 connections and do a lot of test DB prep before hand.

To do so, I need a `DatabaseConfigProvider` implementation. In this case, I need a `JdbcProfile` config. The trait I'm extending is:

```
trait DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[P]
}
```

However, I cannot get the signature of `DatabaseConfigProvider`'s method to type check.

```
class TestDbProvider(config:DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]) extends DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[P] = config
}
```

The above implementation, and many other variants all fail.

```
[error] RepositoryTest.scala:78: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : slick.backend.DatabaseConfig[slick.driver.JdbcProfile]
[error]  required: slick.backend.DatabaseConfig[P]
[error]     def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[P] = config
[error]                                                     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (api/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

More bad variants:

```
// Fails
class TestDbProvider(config:DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]) extends DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = config
}

// Fails
class TestDbProvider[P <: BasicProfile](config:DatabaseConfig[P]) extends DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[P]: DatabaseConfig[P] = config
}

// Fails
class TestDbProvider(config:DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]) extends DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[JdbcProfile]: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = config
}
```

What's the trick in Scala to make an implementation of `DatabaseConfigProvider`? Looking through Slick/Play's code base, there is no example of such a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We couldn't find anyway to make this work without using casting. Here is my implementation:

```
def toProvider(dbIn: PostgresDriver.backend.DatabaseDef) = {

    new DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {

      override def db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = dbIn
      override def config: Config = None.orNull // unused
      override def driverIsObject: Boolean = true
      override def driverName: String = "org.postgresql.Driver"
      override val driver: JdbcProfile = ExtendedPostgresDriver
    }

    new DatabaseConfigProvider {
      // Cast is necessary, otherwise cannot get to compile
      override def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[P] = config.asInstanceOf[DatabaseConfig[P]]
    }
}
```